# Trouble dual booting Kubuntu - Win10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, windows-10

I'm trying to dual boot Kubuntu on my Acer Swift 3 (Win10 already installed), however, **after every time I reboot after installing, it boots straight to Windows.** Pressing F12 displays `Windows Boot Manager` as the only option.

I've already tried the following:

- Installing Kubuntu alongside windows 10 from live USB, bootloader on sda
- Reinstalling with bootloader on sda6 (Linux install partition)
- Running Boot-Repair from live usb
- Doing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` (from tutorial somewhere)

None have worked, every time it only boots straight to Windows, no GRUB. Perhaps the BIOS can only run the Windows Boot Manager?

Any suggestions?

~~~~

My BIOS is set to UEFI boot w/secure boot off. Using Legacy only displays something like `No bootable disk detected. Insert bootable disk and press any key to continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the EFI was disabling `grubx64.efi` from booting. By entering the `security` tab in the bios and under the `add new file to efi` option, added the grub file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to change the order of the EFI in the BIOS: 
It showed Windows as the first, but I cold move the Kubuntu partition upwards, 
save and reboot. From then on it showed the GRUB loader with all options again. Me happy!